# TypeError: _Firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.db.collection is not a function firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
import { initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'key',
    authDomain: 'facebook-clone-nextjs-2dcc9.firebaseapp.com',
    projectId: 'facebook-clone-nextjs-2dcc9',
    storageBucket: 'facebook-clone-nextjs-2dcc9.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '662489031143',
    appId: '1:662489031143:web:ae71393e61a214e3f35d42',
    measurementId: 'G-VFB246J0M5',
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getStorage(firebaseApp);

export { db };

    const sendpost = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!inputRef.current.value) return;

        db.collection('post').add({
            message: inputRef.current.value,
            name: session.user.name,
            email: session.user.email,
            image: session.user.image,
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.fieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
        inputRef.current.value = '';

    };
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 4):

The issues are:

- You are using modular SDK so you cannot use `db.collection()`
- You should use `getFirestore` to get an instance of Firestore but you are using `getStorage` which will get an instance of Storage.

Try refcatoring your code to this:

```
import { getFirestore, collection } from "firebase/firestore"

const db = getFirestore(app)

const colRef = collection(db, "posts")

await addDoc(colRef, {
  ...yourDataObject
});
```

You can learn more about the new syntax in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getFirestore` to get an instance of `Firestore`, but you are using `getStorage` which will get an instance of `Storage`.