# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.db.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add usersOrderInfo collection inside users document.I tried this way:

```
db
.collection('shopDB')
.doc(user.uid)
.collection("userOrderInfo")
.doc(paymentInfo.id)
.set({
orders:basket,created:paymentIntent.created},{merge:true})
```

But this throw an error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.db.collection is not a function
```

I am using firebase version 10.5.0

Answer (score 0):

The set() takes data of document as parameter. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
db
.collection('shopDB')
.doc(user.uid)
.collection("userOrderInfo")
.doc(paymentInfo.id)
.set(DOC_DATA)
```

Also do ensure that no field is undefined.

Comment: now another error occured "db.collection not a function

Comment: What is you firebase version?

Comment: firebase V:10.5.0

Comment: What should i do bro?

Comment: @AML please share your package.json

Comment: "dependencies":{"firebase": "^9.6.9",}

Comment: You should use the new modular SDK. checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030610/typeerror-firebase-webpack-imported-module-6-db-collection-is-not-a-functio